# Is the history.pushState() state object meant for something like this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, pushstate, popstate

I'm loading pages via AJAX, and recently read about `history.pushState` and `onpopstate`.

I didn't really get what the state object parameter is all about in `pushState`, and the page over at MDN only gave a simple object as an example. But I thought, hey, why don't I use this object to store the AJAX response HTML and load that when `onpopstate` fires? So I'm doing something like this:

**On XHR status 200/304 (AJAX success)**:

```
if (history.pushState) {
    var state = {
        html: xhr.responseText
    };
    history.pushState(state, null, url);
}
```

**onpopstate**:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) { 
    if(event && event.state) {
        someDivInTheDoc.innerHTML = event.state.html;
    } else {
        location.reload();
    }
};
```

This, of course, would load (old) content that might have gotten updated, making it something similar to when you go back and get the browser's cache, I guess.

Over at MDN, it says that the object can hold up to 640k characters in its JSON representation.

**So, was the state object meant for something like this? Or should I just force a reload/do an AJAX request again when history moves position?**

Thanks.